# How do you implement nested HTML inside a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I just started doing web dev using AngularJS. I'm pulling [JSON data](http://html5news.herokuapp.com/category/1) and inside the strings of the pulled data is HTML break lines. For example:

```
 { main:  {
          "id": 1,
          "fullStory": "Random sentence. `<br><br>` Another sentence!"}}
```

I'm currently binding these JSON strings to a div. AngularJS code:

```
$http.get('http://html5news.herokuapp.com/category/' + $routeParams.catId)
.success(function(data){
     $scope.categoryData = data;
}
```

HTML code:

```
`<div id="cpMainArticleContent">
     {{categoryData.main.fullStory}}
</div>`
```

The string is appearing as:

> Random sentence. `<br><br>` Another sentence!

What is the most efficient way to execute the HTML code so it displays like this:

> Random sentence. 
>  Another sentence!

Comment: `ng-bind-html` could be helpful

Comment: Remove the backticks?

Comment: The backticks are just there so you can see them, otherwise stackoverflow will implement the breaklines.

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to validate your JSON first. The second JSON(the one you have posted as example) is an invalid one. Try validating it [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSON. This is about how your sending the data to the view. What you need to do is use [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to mark the string as HTML-trusted- and then use [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to display it.

```
$scope.fullStoryHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(categoryData.main.fullStory);
```

Then in your view:

```
<div id="cpMainArticleContent" ng-bind-html="fullStoryHtml"></div>
```

PS. You may also want to strip the back ticks. :)

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/virije/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried this and the string is no longer displaying on the webpage. Is there more setup required other than including $sce as a parameter in my AngularJS controller?

Comment: Your controller needs to require the `$sce` service. You need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` to wrap your HTML-string in a special, trusted object that the `ngBindHtml` directive knows how to work with- and then you need to assign the wrapped value to your `$scope` so you can pass it to `ngBindHtml`. I could put up a Plunker for you if you'd like an example.

Comment: The first time I implemented this solution and it didn't display I used: "=$sce.trustAsHtml(categoryData.main.fullStory);" instead I changed it to the pulled in-scope data variable: "=$sce.trustAsHtml(data.main.fullStory);" and now it works perfectly! Thanks!! :)

Comment: No problem. :) Glad it helped. Give it a check when you can so others who stumble on this entry will know it's a working solution.

Comment: Done. I'll also up-vote it when I get the reputation.